# Django date format by an user

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm writing a Django application that requered to give the user the ability to create his own time format, over an API (problay GraphQl). I've figure out the following way, but it seems to be really hard solution for relativlly small problem.

```
class Formatter(models.Model):
...


class DateLetter(models.Model):

    formatter = models.ForeignKey(Formatter,
                                  related_name="letters",
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    index = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    letter = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                              unique=True,
                              choices=LetterChoices.CHOICES,
                              default=LetterChoices.Y)
```

And after that, just going with some sort of loop to get the instance as a date format (%Y-%m-%d) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right that creating an entire database model just to represent a string is a pretty hardcore solution. Here are 2 alternative ways to do it:

1. Use a regular field and [Django's regex validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#regexvalidator) to validate that the input string only contains certain characters:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class Formatter(models.Model):
    letters = models.CharField(max_length=6, validators=[RegexValidator(r"^[YyMmDd]{6}$")])
```

2. Don't let users type their own format at all, and instead ask them *which locale* they would like to use for dates. You can activate a locale and get the list of its date formats like so:

```
>>> from django.utils.translation import activate
>>> from django.utils.formats import get_format
>>> activate('sv_SE') # locale for Sweden
>>> get_format('DATE_FORMAT')
'j F Y'
```